# C# wpf , partial ListView binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I have a List with 100 items , like:

```
List<User> items = new List<User>();
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "john@doe-family.com" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Mail = "jane@doe-family.com" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13, Mail = "sammy.doe@gmail.com" });
            lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items;
```

and I binding with WPF

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Name: " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text=", " />
                        <TextBlock Text="Age: " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" (" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mail}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                        <TextBlock Text=")" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

How can I binding only part of this list? for example only the items that in index 3-7 ?

I know that I can create a new List, but is there any smart way ?

Comment: `lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items.Skip(3).Take(4);` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items.GetRange(startIndex, count);
```

You could also use LINQ to filter the items in different ways, for example:

```
lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items.Where(item => item.Age > 20);
lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items.Where(item => item.Name.Contains("J"));
```